# §3.3.Irreducibility theorem and thin sets from 『Topics in Galois theory』(Serre)

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, covering-spaces

I'm reading [§3.3.Irreducibility theorem and thin sets] from 『Topics in Galois theory』(Serre). I have a problem on reading the following paragraph.

> Let $\pi:W→V$ be a Galois covering with Galois group $G$, where $V$,$W$ denote $K$-irreducible varieties, $V=W/G$, and $G$ acts faithfully on $W$. Let us say that $P\in V(K)$ has property $Irr(P)$ if $P$ is ``inert", i.e. the inverse image of $P$ (in the scheme sense) is one point, i.e. the affine ring of the fiber is a field $K_{P}$ (or, equivalently, $G_{K}$ acts freely and transitively on the $\overline{K}$-points of $W$ above $P$). In this case, $\pi$ is étale above $P$ and the field $K_{P}$ is a Galois extension of $K$ with Galois group $G$.

1. What is the exact meaning of the inverse image of $P$? point of $W$ defined over $\overline{K}$ or $K$?
2. What is $K_{P}$? In usual sense, $K_{P}$ is the residue field at $P$. However, the residue field at $P\in V(K)$ is just $K$ and the Galois group of $K$ over $K$ is trivial.
3. Could you explain why the Galois group of the extension $K_{P}/K$ is $G$ if $P$ is inert?

Comment: The text states that it's working with the scheme-theoretic inverse image. How much do you know about schemes?

Comment: I know that $V(K)$ is the set of the sections and the fiber(the inverse image of a point) is defined by the fiber product.